# can anyone pinpoint the error in my recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

this function prints all triplets in an array whose product is a number `k`
 input first line number of elements, second array elements, third target product .. passes parameters to recursive function `f` along with a vector that stores elements whose product might give `k`

thought process -> for each element we can include or exclude it to get the product `k`. If `p > 24` or number elements multiplied > `3` we backtrack. once the `prod = k`, we print all numbers from vector `v` and pop them out and set number of elements count to `0` and product to `1` and continue

for an input of:

```
9
1 2 3 12 4 7 5 24 9
24
```

my output looks something like this :

```
12 
2 
1 
9 
9 
9 
| ->cursor justs stops here ..no further outputs...
```

naming scheme used :

**count** -> number of elements multiplied till now whose product  is stored in -> **p**

n-> number of elements in array

k -> target pdt

i -> index of element in array currently at

code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// all triplets whose product is a number k

void f(int i, int count, int p, int k, vector<int>&v, int *a, int n)
{
    // success condition
    if(count == 3 && p == k)
    {
        for(int i = 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            cout << v[i] << " " << endl;
            v.pop_back();
        }
        p = 1;
        count = 0;
    }
    if(count>=3 || i > n - 1 || p > k) 
    {
        return;
    }

    v.push_back(a[i]);
    f(i + 1, count + 1, p * a[i], k, v, a, n);
    v.pop_back();
    f(i + 1, count, p, k, v, a, n);

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *a=new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    //int p = 1;

    vector<int>v;
    f(0, 0, 1, k, v, a, n);

    delete[] a;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The naming scheme used makes the code look like alphabet soup. Not only does this make debugging harder, it is a disincentive to even try.

Comment: It is unnecessary to pass `count` around when that information is readily available as `v.size()` already.

Comment: you are already using `std::vector`, why not also for `a` ?

Comment: @user4581301 ur right but I was in a hurry ...added naming scheme list

Comment: Recommendation: Run the program in a debugger. Wait for it to stop outputting. Interrupt the program and see where it got stuck. Step through a few loops of whatever's preventing the program from proceeding. If this doesn't reveal the error to you, update the question with what you have learned.

Comment: @MaxLanghof oh yeah new to c++ forgot about that function. but do u think its better compute it every time in the function or to just pass it ..which is more efficient ?

Comment: if you have to explain variable names as "n -> number of elements in the array" then you should have rather named the variable `number_of_elements_in_the_array` in the first place. Limits on line lengths limited variables names something like 50 years ago. Nowadays with IDEs autocompletion there is no excuse not to use meaningful names

Comment: @dagwood "Better" in what sense? Your code should be correct and readable, then you can worry about performance. But the `.size()` call definitely won't be the bottleneck in this code either way.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 just used to taking inputs from user in an array. is using a vector more efficient ?? also, I was in a hurry to code this ..was trying competitve programming...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 ...but please don't actually use `number_of_elements_in_the_array`. `arrayLength` would be fine (as would be `n` imo), or `lengthOfA` or similar.

Comment: prefering vector over c-arrays is not primarily for performance, but rather for less bugs, and having the size readiliy available (and to a small extend to avoid the wtf-moment when you show the code to someone else ;)

Comment: @MaxLanghof sometimes my very first trial actually does read `number_of_elements_in_the_array`. On next refactoring, I would realize that I dont need it because I can use a `vector` (just to stay with this example), or pick a better name. I really think `number_of_elements_in_the_array` is more clear than `n`

Comment: @MaxLanghof my success case checks if product p is = to target product and when number of elements is 3 then print those 3 no.s and it empties the vector as and when each number is printed so all 3 are removed hence count = 0 !

Comment: @dagwood Oh right, the `pop_back` is in the loop. My bad.

Comment: Don't call your product `p`, call it `product`.  Don't call your function `f`, call it `FindTriplets`.  We're programmers here, and we get to use *comprehensible variable names*.  We're not mathematicians or scientists who still feel the need to try and make everything fit on a chalk board.  Programmers.  Programmers understand that at least half the point of naming things is to communicate *to our fellow humans* what things mean and how they're used.  *Experienced* programmers know that "fellow human" just might be themselves in six months.

Comment: And overloading a variable name is pretty bad too.  You have a parameter `i` and a loop index variable `i` in the same scope.  I can't think of a single situation where that's a good idea.

Comment: *can anyone pinpoint the error in my recursive function?* -- To be honest, no programmer should resort to asking this question.  Every programmer, if they wrote the code themselves, would know where the error is in their program.  *How* to fix the program -- that's a different situation, where it is reasonable to not know how to fix a problem.  But to ask "where is my problem" -- that's a big minus.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The hard part in fixing most bugs (in my experience) is finding the problem.  What to do to fix it once it's been identified is often as not trivial.  (And every once in a while you have to refactor whole swathes of your application)  Asking for help finding a bug is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your “reset” of `p` and `count` on success is immediately strange: why does the function need to keep looking when its caller will already try the other possibilities?  But that’s just a distraction from the real issue: the balanced `push_back` and `pop_back` around the first recursive call establish and rely on an **invariant** where every call leaves `v` the same length as when it started.  But the success path *clears* the `vector` and leaves it shorter, so eventually you `pop_back` when it’s empty and—

The joys of undefined behavior (which happened to give an infinite loop here) aside, the fix is trivial: just return after printing without **modifying** `v` at all.  (Then you may find some further simplifications.)

Comment: ohhhh yes you are right and coming to think of it right now thats so obvious ..dunno why I didn't of it. thanks a lot for taking the time to look at my code :')